# Wrap Text Over Image CSS

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am wanting to wrap the text within this image. (svg file) I've included the HTML/CSS as well as a visual. [Rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyR4c.png)

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV4wL.png)

[CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW7u1.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add your code in text to your question rather than posting an image of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the same width like image to the .covertext

```
.covertext {
    width: 100px;
 }
```